# Unable to get right jmeter response

Tags: jmeter

I have a post request and the response is success
Initially, I was able to execute the jmeter script and get the correct response but from today Im getting the below issue while testing a portal even though there is no changes made in the portal.
Im not understanding were am I going wrong. Kindly help me

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you recorded your test using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) and the recording included some hard-coded [Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) or [Token](https://jwt.io/)

Initially it was working because the Cookie or token was active and "today" is expired and cannot be used anymore.

Basically it means that your script is missing [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start), you need to:

1. Identify the dynamic parameters used in your test
2. Use suitable JMeter [Post-Processors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) to extract them into [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)
3. Replace recorded hard-coded values with the JMeter Variables from the previous step

See [Advanced Load Testing Scenarios with JMeter: Part 1 - Correlations](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-load-testing-scenarios-jmeter-part-1-correlations) article for more information and examples if needed.